# Transform property makes my text blurry

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text

```
<div class="container valign-transform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h4>Text</h4>
        </div>
    </div> 
 </div>

.vertical-center {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

An example can be found on CodePen: http://codepen.io/LuckyDaniel/pen/YXdxrr

I am trying to vertically align my container by appending the class 'vcenter-transform'. The problem is that my container has display:table on pseudo-selector (clearfix) and that makes all my text to be blurred.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your container in Bootstrap. Fixed the problem for me in the codepen you provided.

```
-webkit-filter: blur(0px);
```

And for other browsers:

```
-moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
```

Comment: I can't see any difference

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing `content: '';` fixes your issue:

```
.container:before, .row:before {
    display: table;
}
```

Alternatively, adding `position: absolute;` also seems to correct your issue:

```
.container:before, .row:before {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it out? I tested this is multiple browsers and the blur is gone on all of them when adding "position: absolute;" to your container.